# Radio button empty value when clicking on label

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am having some odd behavior with a radio button , as you can see in the GIF attached.

When i click on the label the selected value gets cleared and the radio buttons will become empty with none of the values checked

I could not find the cause of the issue .

I am just using basic radio buttons

`

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 15px">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.admin)</td>
    <td class="Admin-class"></td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="radio"    id="radioYes"  name="radioAdmin" value="Yes" /><label for="radioYes">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.yes)</label></td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="radio"    id="radioNo"   name="radioAdmin" value="No" checked /><label for="radioNo">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.no)</label></td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="error-log" name="ErrorLog" disabled>@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.errorLog)</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 15px">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.auditor)</td>
    <td class="Auditor-class"></td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioYesAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="Yes" /><label for="radioYes">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.yes)</label></td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioNoAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="No" checked /><label for="radioNo">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.no)</label></td>
</tr>
```

[image: odd behavior]

Comment: Maybe this is coz of the class you have given to radio `(checkbox)`. BTW are you using any framework?

Comment: copy paste error..... copied same attribute and did not change it to match the proper ids of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same `label for` in the radio buttons below the checkboxes. It should be

```
<input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioYesAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="Yes" />
<label for="radioYesAudit">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.yes)</label>
```

Not as it is now

```
<input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioYesAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="Yes" />
<label for="radioYes">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.yes)</label>
```

It is the same for the `radioNoAudit` radio button

Comment: I changed the label for attribute but still same behavior 
what i am not getting why the clicking on the label affects the radio buttons ? 

FYI the radio fields are behaving properly with the values i want when clicked inside them

Comment: Because it is designed that way, that is what `for="radioYes"` is for. If you do not want clicking on the labels then remove that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your Label for Radio YES, so that's why you are not seeing the radio button filled in the right place.

```
<td><input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioYesAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="Yes" /><label for="radioYesAudit">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.yes)</label></td>
                <td><input class="checkbox" type="radio" id="radioNoAudit" name="radioAuditor" value="No" checked /><label for="radioNoAudit">@Html.Raw(Dashboard.ResourcesLanguage.Language.no)</label></td>
```